# Keep div hidden on click - Cookies

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, toggle

I have a website with a webpage, and two boxes of texts that can be toggled off by clicking the "X" at the top of the boxes. This will close the boxes. But when you reload the page, they come back. I was wondering if there was a way I could make it so that when a user clicks them off for the first time, they stay closed, even when reloading. As they wouldn't need to view the information a second time. Here is the website URL.

Can I do this with cookies, or is there some other way? I have set up one small box using the same code that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

The first function will check to see if the cookie exists. If it does exist hide the div. The next function is for creating the cookie. When the exit button is clicked you set the cookie. First parameter is the cookie name, second parameter is set to true, and third is number of days until the cookie expires

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEquals = name + '=';
    var crumbs = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i<crumbs.length; i++) {
        var crumb = crumbs[i];
        if (crumb.indexOf(nameEquals) == 0) {
            return unescape(crumb.substring(nameEquals.length, crumb.length));
    }
}
return null;
}
//if the cookie exists
if(getCookie("CookieName")){
    //the ID for my promo code input box
    $('#CookieDiv').hide();
} else{
    $('#CookieDiv').show();
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
                var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
            }
            else var expires = "";
            document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
        }
$('#exitButton').click(function(){
createCookie("CookieName","true",1); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use cookies, I would recommend something along these lines with localStorage http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage:

```
$(".closebtn img").click(function(){
    localStorage.announced = true;
    $(this).closest(".announce").fadeOut();
});
```

Then on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined" && localStorage.announced){
        $(".announce").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only work locally? And this doesn't seem to be working, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

```
$(function() {

if (localStorage) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('ShopMess')) {
        $('.messagetop').show();

        $('.closebtn').click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('ShopMess', true);
        return false;
});
    }
} else {
    $('.messagetop').show();
}

$('.closebtn').click(function() {
    $('.messagetop').show('slow');
    return false;
});

$('.closebtn').click(function() {
    $('.messagetop').slideUp(200);
    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Glad to see you went with localStorage.